Hilt doesn't work with Jetpack Compose in AOSP
I am developing an Android application in AOSP.
Below is my configuration for my app Android.bp
    android_library_import {
    name: "MyApp-hilt-navigation-compose",
    aars: ["libs/hilt-navigation-compose-1.2.0.aar"],
}
android_library_import {
    name: "MyApp-hilt-android",
    aars: ["libs/hilt-android-2.50.aar"],
}
android_library {
    name: "MyApp-feature-demohomecpp",
    platform_apis: true,
    srcs: [
        "src/main/**/*.kt",
    ],
    manifest: "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",
    static_libs: [
        "car-ui-lib",
        "androidx.activity_activity-ktx",
        "androidx.annotation_annotation",
        "androidx.appcompat_appcompat",
        "androidx.activity_activity",
        "androidx.recyclerview_recyclerview",
        "androidx.cardview_cardview",
        "com.google.android.material_material",
        "androidx.navigation_navigation-compose",
        "androidx.compose.runtime_runtime",
        "androidx.activity_activity-compose",
        "androidx.navigation_navigation-compose",
        "androidx.compose.ui_ui",
        "androidx.compose.ui_ui-tooling",
        "androidx.compose.ui_ui-tooling-preview",
        "androidx.compose.material3_material3",
        "jetbrains-annotations",
        "hilt-android",
        "MyApp-hilt-navigation-compose",
        "MyApp-asis",
        "MyApp-core-cpp",
        "MyApp-core-common",
        "MyApp-core-ui",
        "MyApp-core-utils",
        "MyApp-data",
        "MyApp-runtime-android"
    ]
}

After making the module successfully by command: m MyApp, I installed the apk file in the devices. However, when the application started up, the below error was explored.
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp.sample, PID: 30878 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/hilt/navigation/HiltViewModelFactory; 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.HiltViewModelKt.createHiltViewModelFactory(HiltViewModel.kt:95) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at com.myapp.sample.feature.demo.demoScreenKt.demoScreen(demoScreen.kt:408) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at com.myapp.sample.feature.demo.navigation.demoNavigationKt$demoScreen$1.invoke(demoNavigation.kt:18) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at com.myapp.sample.feature.demo.navigation.demoNavigationKt$demoScreen$1.invoke(demoNavigation.kt:17) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:138) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:310) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:308) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:308) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:292) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:138) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:801) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:790) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:117) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedEnterExitImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:773) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:772) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:755) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:108) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt.AnimatedContent(AnimatedContent.kt:815) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:277) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$16.invoke(Unknown Source:27) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$16.invoke(Unknown Source:10) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:192) 
10-30 07:20:57.720 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2511) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2780) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3259) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3210) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:864) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1125) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:124) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:580) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:548) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:41) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1341) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1352) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:952) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:878) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1326) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8248) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime:  Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@ce858c2, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@20516d3, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@3513210, AndroidUiDispatcher@f336109] 
10-30 07:20:57.721 E 30878    30878    AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.hilt.navigation.HiltViewModelFactory 

Below is the code of the error block:
@Composable
internal fun DemoHomeCCPScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    demoHomeCCPState: DemoHomeCCPState = rememberDemoHomeCCPState(),
    viewModel: DemoHomeCCPViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navigateToScreen: (String) -> Unit,
) {
}

How to resolve this issue when building the application in AOSP?

Including the Hilt AAR isn't going to work because Hilt utilizes code generation and thus requires deeper integration into the build process.
AOSP already has Hilt checked in with a complete Soong integration in external/dagger2. Notice the many plugins declared in the Android.bp there.
Thus you should not include Hilt AARs, instead include Hilt in AOSP by referencing the pre-existing Soong dagger2 static lib like so:
    static_libs: [
        "androidx.activity_activity-compose",
        "androidx.compose.foundation_foundation",
        "androidx.compose.runtime_runtime",
        "androidx.compose.ui_ui",
        "androidx.hilt_hilt-navigation-compose",
        "hilt_android",
    ],

See this project that is part of AOSP for a working example:
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/c97d572245aad0bd11bc2e89a0f50dcbdf53f6ae:packages/providers/MediaProvider/photopicker/Android.bp;bpv=1
